# Cycle in the struct layout that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, constructor, struct, member, cyclic-reference

This is a simplified version of some of my code:

```
public struct info
{
    public float a, b;
    public info? c;

    public info(float a, float b, info? c = null)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

The problem is the error `Struct member 'info' causes a cycle in the struct layout.` I'm after struct like value type behaviour. I could simulate this using a class and a clone member function, but I don't see why I should need to.

How is this error true? Recursion could perhaps cause construction forever in some similar situations, but I can't think of any way that it could in this case. Below are examples that ought to be fine if the program would compile.

```
new info(1, 2);
new info(1, 2, null);
new info(1, 2, new info(3, 4));
```

edit:

The solution I used was to make "info" a class instead of a struct and giving it a member function to returned a copy that I used when passing it. In effect simulating the same behaviour as a struct but with a class.

I also created the following question while looking for an answer.

[Value type class definition in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297114/value-type-class-definition-in-c)

Comment: My guess would be that you need to have at least one constructor that doesn't take `info` as a parameter? You're using a default argument, but maybe C# doesn't like that. What happens if you make two constructors?

Comment: Just make it a class; this is not struct data

Comment: `info?` is not a *pointer* to `info`, it's a copy. If you really need this (you shouldn't), why not make your own nullable type which is a `class`? You could even have implicit operators to convert to `YourNullable<T>` from `Nullable<T>`. Of course, it would mean a *boatload* of `YourNullable`s, quite probably eliminating any bonus (if there was any) from having your class being a `struct` :) C# `struct`s aren't C `struct`s.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not legal to have a struct that contains itself as a member. This is because a struct has **fixed size**, and it must be at least as large as the sum of the sizes of each of its members. Your type would have to have 8 bytes for the two floats, at least one byte to show whether or not `info` is null, plus the size of another `info`. This gives the following inequality:

```
 size of info >= 4 + 4 + 1 + size of info
```

This is obviously impossible as it would require your type to be infinitely large.

You have to use a reference type (i.e. class). You can make your class immutable and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to give value-like behaviour, similar to the `String` class.

Comment: +1 good advice on all counts. You could also make the c member of type object, forcing it to be boxed (the constructor could still take a info?). Bit of an ugly though

Comment: this actually works for me. `public info? c;` doesn't give any error, it behaves like reference to struct and reference size is determinable.

Comment: C++ have some restrictions too. The dreaded "error: field has incomplete type" is to prevent exactly this kind of abuse. (why am I searching this in 2020, I dunno)

Answer (score 13):

The reason why this creates a cycle is that `Nullable<T>` is itself a `struct`.  Because it refers back to `info` you have a cycle in the layout (`info` has a field of `Nullable<info>` and it has a field of `info`) .  It's essentially equivalent to the following

```
public struct MyNullable<T> {
  public T value;
  public bool hasValue;
}

struct info { 
  public float a, b;
  public MyNullable<info> next;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The real problem is on this line:

```
public info? c;
```

Since this is a `struct`, C# needs to know the inner `info`/s layout before it could produce outer `info`'s layout. And the inner `info` includes an inner inner `info`, which in turn includes an inner inner inner `info`, and so on. The compiler cannot produce a layout because of this circular reference issue.

Note: `info? c` is a shorthand for `Nullable<info>` which is itself a `struct`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to achieve mutable value semantics of variable-sized items (semantically, I think what you're after is to have `MyInfo1 = MyInfo2` generate a new linked list which is detached from the one started by MyInfo2).  One could replace the `info?` with an `info[]` (which would always either be null or else populated with a single-element array), or with a holder class that wraps an instance of `info`, but the semantics would probably not be what you're after.  Following `MyInfo1 = MyInfo2`, changes to `MyInfo1.a` would not affect `MyInfo2.a`, nor would changes to `MyInfo1.c` affect `MyInfo2.c`, but changes to `MyInfo1.c[0].a` would affect `MyInfo2.c[0].a`.

It would be nice if a future version of .net could have some concept of "value references", so that copying a struct wouldn't simply copy all of its fields.  There is some value to the fact that .net does not support all the intricacies of C++ copy constructors, but there would also be value in allowing storage locations of type 'struct' to have an identity which would be associated with the storage location rather than its content.

Given that .net does not presently support any such concept, however, if you want `info` to be mutable, you're going to have to either put up with mutable reference semantics (including protective cloning) or with weird and wacky struct-class-hybrid semantics.  One suggestion I would have if performance is a concern would be to have an abstract `InfoBase` class with descendants `MutableInfo` and `ImmutableInfo`, and with the following members:

1. `AsNewFullyMutable` -- Public instance -- Returns a new `MutableInfo` object, with data copied from the original, calling `AsNewFullyMutable` on any nested references.
2. `AsNewMutable` -- Public instance -- Returns a new `MutableInfo` object, with data copied from the original, calling `AsImmutable` on any nested references.
3. `AsNewImmutable` -- Protected instance -- Returns a new `ImmutableInfo` object, with data copied from the orignal, calling `AsImmutable` (not `AsNewImmutable`) on any nested references.
4. `AsImmutable` -- Public virtual -- For an `ImmutableInfo`, return itself; for a `MutableInfo`, call `AsNewImmutable` on itself.
5. `AsMutable` -- Public virtual -- For a `MutableInfo`, return itself; for an `ImmutableInfo`, call `AsNewMutable` on itself.

When cloning an object, depending upon whether one expected that the object or its descendants would be cloned again before it had to be mutated, one would call either `AsImmutable`, `AsNewFullyMutable`, or `AsNewMutable`.  In scenarios where one would expect an object to be repeatedly defensively cloned, the object would be replaced by an immutable instance which would then no longer have to be cloned until there was a desire to mutate it.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This may not achieve the goal of "struct like value type behaviour."

One solution is to use an array of one item to essentially get a reference the recursively referenced structure. Adapting my approach to your code looks something like this.

```
public struct info
{
    public float a, b;
    public info? c
    {
        get
        {
            return cArray[nextIndex];
        }
        set
        {
            steps[nextIndex] = value;
        }
    }
    private info?[] cArray;

    public info(float a, float b, info? c = null)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.cArray = new info?[] { c }
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: That only works because arrays are always reference types, so you break the cycle. It would be better to just create a small class to hold the reference.

Comment: Correct in how it works. However, using array quickly is less code than creating a small class.

Comment: Well, you example had an struct, but you are indeed correct.