# Size of struct types

Tags: c#, struct

Does structs in c# have a fixed size? So thats why the following code :

```
struct Person
{
    Person child;
}
```

Will cause infinite cycling problems?
Or because struct types contain their proper value and not a reference?

Comment: type definition != object reference. You are mixing things up here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9296289/961113

Comment: "Will cause infinite cycling problems?" No, it wouldn't, because it will not compile.

Comment: But yes, indeed. This is not going to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, structs in C# are value types, containing the actual data directly. Classes are reference types, like pointers in other languages, containing only a reference to the actual object.

(See the link posted in comments which gives a detailed explanation of the issue)